# how to make my button pick a random word and then after again

Tags: java, arrays, int, element

I've written a program to print out a random word and its definition to a text field when the button is pressed once. I want to have it to print another random word and definition when The button is pressed repeatedly. Any Ideas?
I am new to coding so please take that into consideration.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class RandomWord extends JFrame{
private JTextField wordField;
private JTextField defField;
private JButton nextButton;
private String words[] = {"Petrichor:",//0
                        "Iterate:",//1
                        "Absquatulate:",//2
                        "Anhuiliform:",//3
                        "Argle-bargle:","Argus-eyed:",//4
                        "Automy:",//5
                        "Benthos:",//6
                        "Bibliopole:",//7
                        "Bilboes:",//8
                        "Bruxism:",//9
                        "Borborygmus:",//10
                        "Calipygian:",//11
                        "Callithumpian:",//12
                        "Cereology:",//13
                        "Chad:",//14
                        "Chiliad:"};//15

private String def[] = {"The smell of earth after rain.",//0
                        "To utter or perform repeatedly.",//1
                        "To leave somewhere abruptly.",//2
                        "Resembling an eel.",//3
                        "Copious but meaningless talk or writing.",//4
                        "Vigilant, refering to Argos a Greek mythological watchman with a hundred eyes.",//5
                        "The casting off of a limb or other part of the body by an animal under threat, such as a lizard.",//6
                        "The flora and faunda on the bottom of a sea or lake.",//7
                        "A person who buys and sells books, especially rare ones",//8
                        "An iron bar with sliding shackles, used to fasten prisoners' ankles.",//9
                        "Involantary and habitual grinding of the teeth.",//10
                        "A rumbling or gurgling noise in the intestines.",//11
                        "Having shapely buttocks.","Like a discordant band or a noisy parade.",//12
                        "The study or investigation of crop circles.",//13
                        "A piece of waste paper produced by punching a hole.",//14
                        "A thousand things or a thousand years."};//15

public RandomWord(){
    super("Cool Words -1.5");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    int idx = new Random().nextInt(words.length);
    final String randomWord = words[idx];
    final String randomDef = def[idx];

    wordField = new JTextField("Petrichor",20);
    add(wordField);
    defField = new JTextField("The smell of earth after rain",20);
    add(defField);
    nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    add(nextButton);

    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            wordField.setText(randomWord);
            defField.setText(randomDef);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: don't make it final, and when they click the button that should be when you are generating the random index number.

Comment: Well that was simple. ha ha i feel like an idiot! Thanks a million! works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You are choosing the random word and definition at the constructor was called.
You must to change this to choose the random word and definition when you are click with mouse (inside `actionPerformed` method).

Try with this:

```
public RandomWord(){
    super("Cool Words -1.5");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    wordField = new JTextField("Petrichor",20);
    add(wordField);
    defField = new JTextField("The smell of earth after rain",20);
    add(defField);
    nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    add(nextButton);

    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            // this method is executed when you clicked;
            // The random word and definition must be choose at this moment.
            int idx = new Random().nextInt(words.length);
            wordField.setText(words[idx];);
            defField.setText(def[idx]);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Code dump questions are not appropriate -- but neither are code dump answers. The site and the OP would benefit much more from appropriate explanation rather than a spoonfeed code dump.

Comment: Works like a charm. As i was going through the code to try figure out what was going on exactly I noticed that taking the random array element to a string and then plugging it in was redundant :)

Comment: @CapnCoin Edited with an explanation,If is not enough clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the final keyword in your Strings. Final denotes that the String value cannot be changed after its declaration:

```
   String randomWord = words[idx];

   String randomDef = def[idx];
```